# Is this question constructive? I believe it shouldn't have been closed

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072485/will-building-an-app-in-facebook-increase-the-visibility-of-a-wall-post-compared is related to an SDK that 'programmers commonly used' and it is also stating a specific question: whether a *facebook app* wallpost or a *facebook user* wallpost get more visibility.

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING? (please don't use all caps for emphasis)

Comment: Who's shouting? I used caps to show the difference since that seems to be a misunderstanding in the chat.

Comment: It's better to use italics to draw attention, not caps.

Comment: Using all caps on the internet means you are shouting ;) Only use all caps in acronyms (or, you know, when shouting).

Comment: FFS, you guys are ridiculous. I modified the question so you won't be so butthurt. btw, when someone uses only 1 or 2 words in caps. Its hardly considered shouting given that i wrote a sentence in lowercase for the most part.

Comment: @DigitalFire You ask for a discussion with regards to your question. That's what you're getting. The advice to not use all caps to emphasize a point is not "butthurt". And there are several other changes that could be made to the writing alone. Not that it would make the question appropriate though. In any case, if you don't want advice, don't ask for a discussion.

Answer (score 21):

That's not remotely a programming question.  The fact that you're using an SDK is only tangential to the question at best.

I know it's confusing, because we *are* linked on the [Facebook Developers Support](http://developers.facebook.com/support/) page, but your question isn't really technical in nature.  We can't answer questions about how to get more page views, or about Facebook's terms of service.